# Accessibility issues with modifying DOM with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility

I am developing a website for a report. The majority of the report fits within a column that can be no larger than 800px. However there are a couple of sections of the report that include tables that are just so detailed it is impossible to fit within that space.

The solution I am considering is to use JavaScript/jQuery to detect tables that are too large for the column and turn them into links, that when clicked, brings up a light box using more available screen space and displays the table.

This does not seem to difficult to do… but then I started considering accessibility.

So after detecting the oversized tables should I cut them out of the DOM and store them in a variable or should I hide them?

Do accessibility devices such as screen readers use the original source or do they respect changes made by Javascript?

Comment: screen readers see the same page visual users see.

Answer (score 1):

If you hide the content with display:none then the screen reader will not see it until you toggle that attribute.

You could also rip the content out of the DOM as the screen reader only looks at the rendered DOM.

When you create a lightbox, you will have to set focus into the lightbox in order for the screen reader to read the content.